# Twilio verify phone number using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, phone-number

I am trying to develop an application with [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) using the free trail.
Looks like unless a number is manually verified using the Twilio , I cannot send sms or phone call using the Twilio account number. 
Assuming , I need to verify the number xxx-xxx-yyyy in my application,whats the C# code to implement verify phone number . Here is the screenshot of the feature I would like to implement in c#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the AddOutgoingCallerId method in the .NET helper library to validate new phone numbers.  Calling this method will return to you the 6 digit validation code and make an outgoing call to the phone number provided to the method.

Note that verified phone numbers can only be used to make outgoing voice calls.  You cannot send SMS messages using the verified number as the From number.

Hope that helps.